# Custom Vertical tab

Tags: forms

I am adding a simple select element via form alter to the menu vertical tab on my nodes.
In this select list the user can select an icon that should be displayed with the menu link.

I have implemented the select via the Form API just fine, but when I save the node, the value of this select does not get saved?

I have tried to do some research on this, but I find very mixed informations...
Some claim that the custom settings in the vertical tabs should get saved into the variables table (which is not the case)

Some claim you have to implement a custom schema for this? (to save the nid & the icon class in this case)
But this seems cumbersome for something this simple?

What confuses my is that when you dpm($node) in hook_node_update(). the value IS there?

All advise is welcome!

Comment: You will need to handle storage yourself in either case. I think the most optimal choice is to define a database schema for your table, and store the data there. Variables table is used for general data that is not specific to a particular node.

Comment: does it have to be in a vertical tab? you could also add a custom field for that. then data handling is none of your bussines anymore.

Comment: Dear Aram, Thanks for the feedback.
Indeed, I implemented a custom schema for the storage. You can add this as an answer if you want.